# There is a reason sudoku uses squares

Tags: sudoku

There exists a 9x9 grid with the cells in one single row numbered 1-9 in order.  The cells in the other 8 rows are initially empty.

[image]
<sup>***Note:  The cells initially containing numbers can be in any one row; not necessarily the first.***</sup>

Draw borders to divide the square into 9 non-intersecting continuous regions containing 9 cells each such that you make a sudoku-like puzzle with a unique solution. You may not add any additional numbers or hints.  A sudoku-like puzzle, for this question, has the following rules:

- each cell in the 9x9 grid contains exactly 1 integer between 1 and 9 inclusive
- each row and column and bordered region contains each integer between 1 and 9 inclusive exactly once

Comment: @Will I am asking the user to make a jigsaw sudoku such that all of the initial 9 numbers are in a single row.

Comment: An image would really help here.  It sounds like you're saying the first column is all $1$s, the second column is all $2$s, etc. ("*...cells in a single row numbered 1-9 in order*").  But then you say "*...each ... column ... contains each integer between 1 and 9...*".  That seems to be contradictory.

Comment: There is a single row with the 9 numbers in order. All other rows are empty.

Comment: Something like this? http://i.imgur.com/sWdGcVX.png

Comment: @cyberbit thanks, that works. I didn't want to restrict it to any particular row but whatever.

Comment: I might be looking at this wrong, but can't you just use normal sudoku boundaries to solve this?

Comment: If you make this into a normal sudoku board, it will not have a unique solution. No Sudoku board with a unique solution has every been found with less than 17 squares filled in. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlyTq-xVkQE

Comment: Does it have to be solvable?

Comment: Just to be clear, there are at least 2 solutions to this.  They are both solvable with the original 1-9 row being any of the 9 rows.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a unique solution to the following

> [image]

The solution is

> [image]

Proof of uniqueness

> Let us use the following notation: 
>  The rows from top to bottom are given the labels $A-I$ 
>  The columns from left to right are numbered $1-9$ (as with the top row). 
>  Firstly, $B9$ must be $1$ since it is the last in its continuous region. Then, this forces $C8$ to be $1$ since none of the rest of row $B$ can contain $1$ nor can column $9$. Similarly, we find that going down diagonally to the left all the entries are $1$ down to $I2$. 
>  Now, look at $C9$. The entry here, $x$, must be the same as $D8$, since its continuous region has to contain $x$ but row $C$ and column $9$ already contain $x$. By a similar line of reasoning, we find, recursively, that the entries $E7$, $F6$, $G5$, $H4$ and $I3$ are all $x$ but of course cannot be $3,4,\ldots,9$ so $x=2$ and $B1$ must also be $2$. 
>  We can continue this line of reasoning, next starting at the entry in $D9$, calling this $y$ and proceeding diagonally left and down to find $y=3$. 
>  In this way, we can fill the entire grid, recursively always beginning at the topmost entry in column $9$.

Answer (score 7):

**Side notes and footnotes**

The Sudoku variation in question turns out to be called
[“Du-Sum-Oh,”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#Sudoku_with_irregular_regions)
along with some [aliases](http://www.bumblebeagle.org/dusumoh/),
and cells 1– 8 by themselves
can force a unique solution without being given cell 9.

[Hexomino’s original
 answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/36012/18129)<sup>1</sup>
revealed how delightful this puzzle is
but I had forgotten the details months later
when mentioning it to a fellow Sudoku enthusiast,
so some variety ensued.

> [image]

<sup>(Click within a spoiler to reveal it permanently.)</sup>

The layout on the left, with straightforward numbering,
has a very sleek route to solution <sup>2</sup>
whereas the numbering on the right demonstrates that
an irregular set of initial numbers
can also force a unique solution
and be amusing to solve <sup>3</sup>
if you’re in the mood.

Progress came from starting with small boards while experimenting with
simple zigzags and **L** shapes.
The 4×4 and 5×5 layouts along the way
were misleadingly efficient <sup>4</sup>
and led to an unnecessarily awkward 9×9 layout.

> [image]

---

Footnotes (solutions of layouts):

<sup>1</sup>
Synopsis of the three stages in
[Hexomino’s
 original solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/36012/18129).
(Circles ◯ spotlight cells that were most recently filled
 or are immediately determinable at the steps shown.)

> [image]

<sup>2</sup>
First and last steps of the present straightforward solution.
(Circles ◯ mean the same<sup>1</sup> as above.)

> [image]

<sup>3</sup>
Synopsis of a solution for irregularly placed initial numbers.
(Circles mean the same<sup>1</sup> as above.)

> [image]

<sup>4</sup>
Solutions of the 4×4 layout in just two steps
and of the 5×5 layout in four steps.

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Angel Koh came up with another solution to my layout, so it is non-unique.

I believe to have a unique solution in regular sudoku you need at minimum: 1 number in each column, 1 number in each row, 1 number in each box, and every number from 1-9. But, you can cheat on 1 of these and for instance satisfy the remaining 3 clues but have a number in 8 boxes.

> [image]
>
>   Has a unique solution which is:
>
>   [image]
>
>  Although I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: wouldn't swopping row 2 with any other rows still work?

Comment: @AngelKoh, ya I think you are right.

Comment: No, this solution is not unique. You can swap the 3rd and 4th line with the 5th and 6th line, for instance, and you have found annother solution.

Comment: @AngelKoh Swapping row 2 (from the top) with any of the following lines would invalidate at least the two blocks in the upper left and right.